# Time duration by timedelta in python

Tags: python

`hi
I am trying to find time duration between start time and end time, but I have only one output! is there any solution to select all rows!?
my code is following like this

```
import csv
import datetime
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta,date
f1=open("starttime.csv")
f2=open("endtime.csv")
time_arry_temp = [[]]*5
i=0
for row in csv.reader(f1):
 fmt = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
d1=datetime.strptime(row[0], fmt)
for row in csv.reader(f2):
 fmt = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
d2=datetime.strptime(row[0], fmt)
tdelta = (d2-d1)
if tdelta.days < 0:
   tdelta = timedelta(days=0,seconds=tdelta.seconds,   microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)
t = tdelta * 24 * 60
time_arry=str(t).split()
print (time_arry)
time_arry_temp[i]=time_arry
i=i+1
f1.close()
f2.close()
print(time_arry_temp)
```

Comment: Please fix indention of your code.

Comment: @flasetru I corrected the indention.

Comment: @Mostafa could you correct it with four spaces for indentation?

Comment: @MoonCheesez I corrected it

Comment: why are you importing `datetime` so many times? waht is point of putting `fmt` inside the loop? also you are putting `time_arry_temp[i]=time_arry` which is not inside any loop, so you are always getting only `time_arry_temp[0]` value

Comment: @Eular you mean line 12 and 15!?

Comment: I still have one output, I think I need to change "tdelta = (d2-21)!! any solution??

Comment: your code is a little confusing can you post a sample for the input csv files and your desired output? Then we can be more helpful

Comment: @Eular starttime.csv has five rows like : 12/03/2010 21:00  and also endtime.csv has five rows like: 13/03/2010 22:00 and then I want to obtain the time difference between each row of these two files!

Comment: and that `if` condition block, can you explain what are you trying to to there?

Comment: @Eular This will return a negative result if the end time is earlier than the start time, for example s1 = 12:00:00 and s2 = 05:00:00. If you want the code to assume the interval crosses midnight in this case (i.e. it should assume the end time is never earlier than the start time), you can add the following lines to the above code:

if tdelta.days < 0:
    tdelta = timedelta(days=0,
                seconds=tdelta.seconds, microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've edited your code a little and written this. Check if it does your job.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
get_time=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
with open("starttime.csv") as f , open("endtime.csv") as g:
    d1=[get_time(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(f)]
    d2=[get_time(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(g)]
tdelta = [(a-b) for a,b in zip(d1,d2)]

for n,t in enumerate(tdelta):
    if t.days < 0:
        tdelta[n]=timedelta(days=0,seconds=t.seconds,   microseconds=t.microseconds)

# time_arry_temp =[str(i*24 * 60).split() for i in tdelta]
time_arry_temp =[str(i).split() for i in tdelta]
print time_arry_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one output because all items in `time_arry_temp` poinst to same object, so to fix problem replace line:

```
time_arry_temp = [[]]*5
```

to

```
time_arry_temp = [[] for _ in range(5)]
```

Take a look on [Python Common Gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) article. There are plenty of useful information )

Comment: I still have one output, I think I need to change "tdelta = (d2-21)!!